# Error on Contribution Page with Google Simple Calendar Plugin

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

I'm about to make a contribution page live on a WordPress site that uses the Google Simple Calendar plugin, and when I go to the live contribution page link I get this error:
`[Sat Nov 03 19:33:53.941951 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 21601:tid 140699219515136] [client X.X.X.X:XXXXX] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Carbon\\Carbon' not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/includes/functions/shared.php:230\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/includes/functions/shared.php(155): simcal_get_calendar_names_i18n('month', 'full')\n#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/includes/calendars/views/default-calendar-grid.php(143): simcal_common_scripts_variables()\n#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/google-calendar-events/includes/assets.php(126): SimpleCalendar\\Calendars\\Views\\Default_Calendar_Grid->scripts('.min')\n#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): SimpleCalendar\\Assets->load('')\n#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(A...\n', referer: https://jeffcodemocrats.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fcontribute&reset=1`

When I disable the Simple Calendar plugin the contribution page works fine.

I'm not sure if that's just a general conflict with that plugin such that this won't work, or if there's something else going on that someone might have run into before. Thanks for any ideas anyone has.